# Why can't I login if a vncserver@:x is running?

Tags: rhel, tigervnc

I have enabled a vncserver session for my user but I can't login on the desktop anymore.

Why? How can I enable a vncserver session AND the normal dekstop gnome session on the physical computer?

RHEL8 : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_the_desktop_environment_in_rhel_8/accessing-the-desktop-remotely_using-the-desktop-environment-in-rhel-8#remotely-accessing-the-desktop-as-multiple-users_accessing-the-desktop-remotely